# jQuery search function ( new RegExp)

Tags: jquery, regex

I have following problem. By typing 1-2 characters in the search field #filter the script only should filter elements who starts with these character. For example `an`,`AN`,`An` or `aN` should not show elemtens like `man` but should show elements like `Ankle` or `anchor`.
By typing 3 character: For example `ser` or `SER` should show elements like `Service rules` or `Techno Services`. This works fine with my code. 
I just need help with the filter expression searching for the first 2 letters.

Can someone help me pls?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#filter").keyup(function(){
    var count = $(this).val().length;

    if(count <= '2'){    
      var filter1 = $(this).val();
      $(".filter").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter1, 'i')) < 0) {
          $(this).fadeOut();            
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        }   
      });
    }

    if(count >= '3'){
      var filter = $(this).val();

      $(".filter").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, 'i')) < 0) {
          $(this).fadeOut();            
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        }        
      });        
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: You're looking for an expression for `filter1` then? `'^' + filter1 + '.*'` See a demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/9jRGKj/1

Comment: @Jan most likely `'\\b' + filter` because he needs to match `Techno Services` for `ser`

Comment: I tried it this way `($(this).text().search(new RegExp('^' + filter1 + '.*')) < 0)`, but it doesn't work. I have element like starting with agf. By typing a it show me nothing. By typing agf the element appears.

Comment: Ok this regex example is exactly what i need but it doesn't work for me. Seem to me i have other problems :(

Comment: side note: `\b` seems what you need, but it works quite bad with unicode accent characters, if you need unicode support, replace it by `(?=^|\W)` (which is probably not perfect but will work in most cases)

Comment: `(new RegExp('\\b' + filter1, 'i'))` i tried it now this way and it works but it shows me elements like `Implementation and Hosting` but i just want elements who starts with an `a`

Comment: well "and" begins by an "a"... welcome to the custom search systems flaws ;) you might want to exclude some special keywords maybe..